# semantic-ui-react superhero Dropdown.Item highlighting

Tags: semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm getting started with semantic-ui-react and trying out the superhero theme from semantic-ui forest.  When using a dropdown menu, the items hovered in the dropdown are highlighted with black text and a nearly black background.

[image: dropdown menu showing dark highlighting]

Is there anything I need to change in order to have either the text or background be a lighter color on hover?

I'm using the out-of-the-box semantic.superhero.min.css file, and below is the dropdown menu react component (using the sample source from semantic-ui-react:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Dropdown, Icon, Input, Menu } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const options = [
  { key: 1, text: 'This is a super long item', value: 1 },
  { key: 2, text: 'Dropdown direction can help', value: 2 },
  { key: 3, text: 'Items are kept within view', value: 3 },
]

export default class MenuBar extends Component {
  state = {}

  handleItemClick = (e, { name }) => this.setState({ activeItem: name })

  render() {
    const { activeItem } = this.state

    return (
      <Menu>
        <Menu.Item>
          <Input placeholder='Search...' />
        </Menu.Item>

        <Menu.Item>
          Home
        </Menu.Item>
        <Dropdown item simple text='Categories'>
          <Dropdown.Menu>
            <Dropdown.Item>Electronics</Dropdown.Item>
            <Dropdown.Item>Automotive</Dropdown.Item>
            <Dropdown.Item>Home</Dropdown.Item>
          </Dropdown.Menu>
        </Dropdown>

        <Menu.Item name='browse' active={activeItem === 'browse'} onClick={this.handleItemClick}>
          <Icon name='grid layout' />
          Browse
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item name='messages' active={activeItem === 'messages'} onClick={this.handleItemClick}>
          Messages
        </Menu.Item>
        <Dropdown item simple text='Left menu' direction='right' options={options} />

        <Dropdown item simple text='More'>
          <Dropdown.Menu>
            <Dropdown.Item icon='edit' text='Edit Profile' />
            <Dropdown.Item icon='globe' text='Choose Language' />
            <Dropdown.Item icon='settings' text='Account Settings' />
          </Dropdown.Menu>
        </Dropdown>
      </Menu>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: A little progress today.  Removing the <Menu> component (and child <Menu.Item> components), restored the proper highlighting for the hovered dropdown items.  However, the menu bar loses a lot of the formatting it inherited from Menu.

Answer (score 1):

This *appears* to be a bug in the semantic-ui-forest superhero theme css.  When I view the demo of the superhero theme, the styling is accurate: http://semantic-ui-forest.com/themes/bootswatch/superhero/

I downloaded the css from that demo, and it corrected the problem I was seeing locally.

I've opened a github issue in the semantic-ui-forest/forest-themes project.
https://github.com/semantic-ui-forest/forest-themes/issues/21